# How do I use my SmartPhone to USB host my old Tablet?

Tags: usb, tablet, usb-tethering

My new moto g7 does not Wi-Fi the correct frequency for my old dragon touch X10.  Android 9 on phone and 5.1.1 on the tablet.  Want to Host from cellular through USB to Client tablet. Any ideas on how to get the internet connection through? Tried PDAnet+ but both devices seem to HOST and I need tablet as client...

Comment: Your phone is connected to internet, right? So if your phone supports USB tethering it'll appear as a USB Ethernet adapter on your tablet which must be supported on your tablet, but is highly unlikely. PDANet requires a client-side software (on PC) which is not available for phones (in USB OTG mode) AFAIK.

Comment: What is the exact problem with the Wifi frequencies? Does your new phone use a unsupported/disallowed channel in 2.4GHz (which one?) or does it only provide a 5GHz hotspot?